# Is it safe to make common ground between multiple voltage planes

Tags: power-supply, current, power-electronics, electricity

I have a system where I have two power inputs and a single power output. One input from a battery(13v, 10A max) and one from solar cells(19v, 10A max). Then there is an 12v output which I connect to a power supply that steps down that 12v to 5v to be used for single board computer and some LEDs.

What I want to do is connect the grounds together. So both the two input grounds and the output ground are connected. I want to do this because I'm creating a system where the power rails have to go over a power connector and if I can let these grounds go over a single pin then it will save me a lot of headaches with the amount of power pins I need.

In addition to this I wonder what kind of rated current I would need for my ground wire/pin. Would 10A(the max of each individual input) suffice or would I need 20A(Sum of both inputs)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you are taking power off your board you will want one return line for every power signal so you can make twisted pairs to reduce coupled magnetic field noise.

Comment: The recipient of all those supplies (the circuit/module that is the far side of the power connector) may not like you joining the grounds.

Comment: I think a schematic would be useful here